# undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x9dee690>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin gem for my small application based on Quiz. But when I execute **rake db:migrate** it gives me error. Following is the trace of the command :

```
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateAdminUsers: migrating =========================================
-- create_table(:admin_users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x9dee690>
/home/users/Documents/Quiz/db/migrate/20120509055635_devise_create_admin_users.rb:4:in `block in change'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters  /abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:432:in `create_table'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/home/users/Documents/Quiz/db/migrate/20120509055635_devise_create_admin_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:119:in `with_connection'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/users/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Follwoing is my GemFile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'haml'
gem 'paperclip'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Content of **20120509055635_devise_create_admin_users.rb** is

```
class DeviseCreateAdminUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:admin_users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    # Create a default user
    AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')

    add_index :admin_users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :admin_users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :admin_users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :admin_users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :admin_users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

end
```

I searched for the above issue and got [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/833) , but this doesn't helped me out. Everywhere I found this solution only.
Does any one came across this issue before, if yes what you did to tackle it? Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had what I think is the same issue, I updated my gem, and dropped my db, later I got a very similar message, then I created a new rails app just to compare and it turns out the migration file has been changed, now it includes the columns instead of calling methods.

I hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks man. Got that working. It was same the issue, migration file was having column names instead of devise method names.

Comment: could you please place the migration code in this answers.

Answer (score 43):

I also ran into this issue on my existing app as I tried to deploy to a new staging server.

Ended up being that the Devise gem had been updated to 2.1 and I hadn't fixed the migration to work correctly with the new version.

Be sure to read through their migration to 2.1 doc on their wiki -- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.1

Also, be sure to read through the doc for how to correctly adjust existing migrations -- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Answer (score 13):

I've run into this twice and there is a really easy solution - instead of db migrations, run this:

```
heroku run rake db:create 
# optionally with --app your_apps_name if you have multiple apps.
```

then:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: rake db:create
rake db:schema:load

These two commands worked for me.

Comment: This leaves the migrations broken.   Probably not a good idea.

Comment: When would this become an issue?

Comment: This resolved my issue when creating a test DB on a legacy app (Yep god help me get thorough this one!)

Comment: if you ran rake db:schema:load by mistake and still want to run your migrations run `rake db:drop:all` then `rake db:create:all` then again `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem might be as result of changes in Devise 2.0 migration schema style. Check out new schema format on the link below. Update migration accordingly and try again. This worked for me especially with #heroku

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Answer (score 2):

New to this site as you can see from my rep. John Kamuchau is correct, you need to change the xxxx_devise_create_users.rb migration according to your version.

For example I just updated a rails 3.2 to 4.2 updating devise accordingly and I had to change out the deprecated -

```
t.database_authenticatable :null => false
```

for -

```
## Database authenticatable
t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
```

Old question but hope this helps if someone comes looking.