# Trouble running all migration files. What else can one do?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a very large amount of migration files that need to run and some of them apparently are outdated. For example:

This fails:

```
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      ...
```

With this error:

```
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition
```

I assume because Devise was updated at the time of writing this.

What else can I do?

It turns out there's a schema file. Here's part of it:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160221211458) do

  create_table "activities", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",                  null: false
    t.string   "target_type", default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "target_id",                null: false
    t.string   "action",      default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "activities", ["target_id"], name: "index_activities_on_target_id_and_target_type", using: :btree
  add_index "activities", ["user_id"], name: "index_activities_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "addresses", force: true do |t|
  ...
```

What's the difference between doing `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` vs trying to run the migrations. Is there a difference between the two?

Also, this database is a mysql database:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: arthouse_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  #socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

How do I see this database after running `bundle exec rake db:schema:load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This fails:

```
def self.up
 create_table(:users) do |t|
 t.database_authenticatable :null => false
```

> I assume because Devise was updated at the time of writing this.

**I need to know the error messages you get**

> It turns out there's a schema file:

In your schema I see that you have not `users` table, I think that you [need to check your db `mysql2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200215/how-to-log-in-to-mysql-and-query-the-database-from-linux-terminal#6200257) and see if you have something there.

> What's the difference between doing `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` vs trying to run the migrations. Is there a difference between the two?

let's say I fork a github project and the `schema` file is already populated. With that command I load the schema so I do not run every migration but just create the tables like in the schema.

Migrations use scripts to populated the database, this scripts have function like [`add_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) that modify the `schema.rb` file.

Every function from [ActiveRecord:Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) will modify the schema, this means maybe adding a column and later deleting. This conflict in migrations are cause by the incompatibility in this migrations, for example you add a column, then you need to reverse it, but later you add an index to that column, so the migration fails. More info at the following [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

> Migrations are a convenient way to alter your database schema over time in a consistent and easy way. They use a Ruby DSL so that you don't have to write SQL by hand, allowing your schema and changes to be database independent.
>
> You can think of each migration as being a new 'version' of the database. A schema starts off with nothing in it, and each migration modifies it to add or remove tables, columns, or entries. Active Record knows how to update your schema along this timeline, bringing it from whatever point it is in the history to the latest version. Active Record will also update your db/schema.rb file to match the up-to-date structure of your database.

### Solution

Your error

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition
```

Given your problem, you should find the solution hear

[undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x9dee690>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630768/undefined-method-database-authenticatable-for-activerecordconnectionadapte#10731177)

Comment: the schema file is just a segment of the schema file

Comment: @Jwan622 notify me when you provide me more info

Comment: @Jwan622 do you think this will work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630768/undefined-method-database-authenticatable-for-activerecordconnectionadapte#10731177

Comment: this is dope dawg

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes. It is. I would include a reference to that question and if no other problem comes out feel free to accept it. Thanks a lot. Fabrizio

Comment: But in terms of trying to get a database up and running, why wouldn't people just use `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` instead of running the migrations which might be broken?

Comment: @Jwan622 that does not make sense, what if they want to revert the db to a specific migration? It is not good. I never do that. I am against it. Migrations needs to work, but some people do like you say. They just run `rake db:schema:load` then they run the migration, they never migrate down.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue on my existing app as I tried to deploy to a new staging server.

Ended up being that the Devise gem had been updated to 2.1 and I hadn't fixed the migration to work correctly with the new version.

Be sure to read through their migration to 2.1 doc on their wiki -- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.1

Also, be sure to read through the doc for how to correctly adjust existing migrations -- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style